# Why Goldstein's book is claiming that radius and angle doesn't contain time variable even there is $\dot{r}$ and $\dot{\theta}$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, angular-momentum, conservation-laws, coordinate-systems

$$L=\frac{1}{2}m(\dot{r}^2+r^2\dot{\theta}^2)-V(r)$$
$$p_\theta=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta}=mr^2\dot{\theta}$$
$$\dot{p}_\theta=\frac{d}{dt}(mr^2\dot{\theta})$$

Goldstein wrote that $\dot{P}_\theta=0$. I know $r$ and $\theta$ both (function) have time variable. Although why he wrote differentiation of momentum respect to time is 0?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello! It is [preferable](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/) to type out screenshots or images of text; for formulae, one can use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Comment: That isn't what is stated. The angular momentum is conserved, so there is no time variation of the angular momentum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that $r$ and $\theta$ are functions of time, and Goldstein is not claiming that they arent. The whole point of the discussion is that $p_{\theta}$ is a constant, even though it may not appear so at first since $r = r(t)$ and $\theta = \theta(t)$. This follows from the Euler Lagrange equations, there is one for each generalized coordinate
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial \dot \theta} =  \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial \theta}, \qquad \frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial \dot r} =  \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial r}.
$$
The first one implies
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \underbrace{\frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial \dot \theta}}_{\equiv p_{\theta}} = \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial \theta} = 0.
$$